# Connecting two devices via VXLAN

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I am currently trying to get in touch with vxlan. For this I wanted to setup a VXLAN on two of my boxes and connect them via VXLAN.

I have the following /etc/network/interfaces configuration on Host1:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp2s0f1 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.xxx.12
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        bridge_ports enp2s0f1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

auto enp2s0f0
iface enp2s0f0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.12
        netmask 255.255.0.0

auto vx0
iface vx0 inet static
        mtu 1600
        pre-up ip link add vx0 type vxlan id 10 group 238.182.226.153 dev enp2s0f1 || true 
        up ip link set vx0 up
        down ip link set vx0 down
        post-down ip link del vx0 || true
        address 10.1.1.12
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The configuration on my second host looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp2s0f1 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.xxx.13
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.254
        bridge_ports enp2s0f1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

auto enp2s0f0
iface enp2s0f0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.13
        netmask 255.255.0.0

auto vx0
iface vx0 inet static
        mtu 1600
        pre-up ip link add vx0 type vxlan id 10 group 238.182.226.153 dev enp2s0f1 || true
        up ip link set vx0 up
        down ip link set vx0 down
        post-down ip link del vx0 || true
        address 10.1.1.13
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The multicast address is working fine (I have tested it via iperf). With wireshark I can see that Host1 sends ARP Request to the broadcast address and is searching for Host2 / 10.1.1.13 but there is no answer.. any idea?

Also: When I try to restart networking it throws an error, the interface exists but it isn't up. But I can set it up manually.